# No matter what I do, I get this error avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbe

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, avrdude

My problem is no matter what I do to upload a blink program to my Arduino pro-mini, I'm getting the not in sync error(below I have attached the error for reference).

Let me briefly explain my issue, I've like 60 pro-minis in that 30 are loaded with some code previously(and all are working fine), now  I've lost the code because of my HDD issue(unfortunately I don't have a backup) now the things is I've to code the remaining pro-mini with the same code, I tried to retrieve the code using AVR Dude but I was getting this not in a sync error. later I tried to upload using a blink program from IDE and cmd line too still I was getting the same error while uploading. So, I tried  with another Promini to my surprise same error and another and another I tried all 30 pro-minis all are giving me the same error (All 60 pro--minis are from the same vendor), I tried to upload the blink program to the remaining 30 prominis it worked like a charm. I don't know why the heck, those pms are not syncing. I tried uploading in different ways all to vein.
What I observed is the pm's reset led blinks rapidly for few seconds whenever I connect power and when I press the reset button and while uploading too.
Please help me out here

Here are things I've tried:

- I tried to upload using Arduino uno, Mega, USB - TTL, FTDI...
- changed the USB cable.
- tried with a different computer.

Nothing worked with the preloaded pms but worked with empty pms. I went through a lot of posts for around two weeks nothing worked.

Below is the error message

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Pro or Pro Mini, ATmega328P (5V, 16 MHz)"
Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM11 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\BJI\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_411622/sketch_apr15a.ino.hex:i
```

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619

```
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch
     System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM11

     Using Programmer              : arduino

     Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600

    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xce
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf7
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6b
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa8
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xee
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x4f
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa8
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbe
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xed
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9e

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

An error occurred while uploading the sketch

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using Arduino as ISP programmer. If I try to upload directly it was throwing error but when I upload using a ISP Programmer it works.